# Frequently Prerender is getting stopped. How can i handle this?

Tags: prerender

Using: https://prerender.io/

Frequently getting this error unexpected server response (404) and prerender is stopped.

Right now I have always restarted the server and solving this issue.

I am using pm2 to continue server start.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

got 504 in 16ms for https://www.testing.com/tags/testing1234/1

getting https://www.testing.com/tags/testing1234/1

```
Error: unexpected server response (404)
    at ClientRequest._req.on (/opt/apps/apps/prerender/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:653:21)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:555:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:441:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

Comment: Can you send us an email at support@prerender.io with some more information and a URL that we can reproduce this ourselves? We'd love to help here.